Interfaces, keys and assignment
I have this code:
interface Config1 { A: string; N: number; }
interface Config2 { B: string; N: number; }

interface Config extends Config1, Config2 { }

const config: Partial<Config> = {};
const keys: Array<keyof Config> = ["A", "B", "N"];

const key = keys[0];
config['A'] = 'abc';
config[key] = 'abc';

Playground
I don't understand why the last line is not accepted by TypeScript:
Type '"abc"' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.


The error provided by TypeScript in this case is not great:

Type '"abc"' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
Type '3' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.

However, I think the error detection is correct. Here is some annotated source code trying to make more clear what is happening:
// Creating these to debug what is going on
const key = keys[0];
const a = config['A'];
const b = config[key];

// Here you can debug the types
type K = typeof key; // "A" | "N" | "B"
type A = typeof a; // string | undefined
type B = typeof b; // string | number | undefined

// 1. OK TypeScript knows that when key is 'A' its value is string
config['A'] = 'abc';

// 2. OK When you acces an object via index signature you could get undefined
config['A'] = undefined;

// 3, ERROR Number is not allowed 
// because when the key is 'A' the value is a string
config['A'] = 3;

// 4. ERROR TypeScript knows that key could be "A" | "N" | "B"
// so is not able to be sure about number or string being the right value
config[key] = 'abc';

// 5. Same as point 2
config[key] = undefined;

// 6. Same as point 4
config[key] = 3;


You can see this in the playground.
If you change your keys to:
const keys = ["A", "B", "N"] as const;

The type of K will become "A" instead of "A" | "N" | "B": 
type K = typeof key; // "A"

And then, you will see the errors that you would expect:

Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.


Thanks for your explanations :-)
If I understand correctly, there is no way to assign in a loop:
for (const key of keys) {
config[key] = key !== keys[2] ? 'abc' : 123;
}
?

If you use something automated and don't use constant string literals like const keys = ["A", "B", "N"] as const, TypeScript will probably not be powerful enough to infer the correct types. The more dynamic the type, the more complex it is for TS to infer it correctly.

Explanation
According to the type of keys, Typescript considers that keys[0] can be any key of Config (typeof keys[0] is still keyof Config == 'A' | 'B' | 'N').
For this reason, is is expected that the value you assign to your object
config: Partial<Config> satisfies all potential values at the same time.
In this case, since you used Partial<Config>, expected values are the intersection between string | undefined and number | undefined. And thus, the only overlapping type is undefined.
Do note that had you not used Partial<Config>, expected values would be the intersection between string and number, which does not overlap and thus produce the type never (no values are accepted).
Solution
If your array of keys is constant (in the way you won't change it's content)
A solution could be to define keys the following way: const keys = ["A", "B", "N"] as const;
That would make typescript know the actual value of keys[0] and thus proper typing could be applied to the expected value.
